# Python to group SQL data

Tags: python, pandas

I used to read the data from CSV file, while I just imported all CSV data in SQL database, but I have difficulty in extracting data using Python from SQL.

My original code of read CSV is like this:

```
import pandas as pd
stock_data = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='stock_data_w.csv', parse_dates=[u'date'], encoding='gbk')
stock_data[u'change_weekly'] = stock_data.groupby(u'code')[u'change'].shift(-1)
```

Now I want to read data from SQL, here is my code, but it doesn't work and I am not sure how to sort it out:

```
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='232323', db='test', port=3306)
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM stock_data_w")

stock_data = pd.DataFrame(data=cur.fetchall(),  columns=[i[0] for i in cur.description])
stock_data[u'change_weekly'] = stock_data.groupby(u'code')[u'change'].shift(-1)
```

> the error is: "raise PandasError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!') pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!"

Comment: DataFrame is available now. Go to IDE and use `print stock_data.head()` to see the data and `stock_data.columns` to understand what you have in data

Comment: Thanks very much! Finally I sorted out under you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below way to convert your cursor object to crate data frame.

```
stock_data = pd.DataFrame(data=cursor.fetchall(), index=None,
                         columns=cursor.keys())
print stock_data
```

In mysqldb, `columns=[i[0] for i in cursor.description]`

or

Make your connection with alchemy and use,

```
stock_data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from stock_data_w",
                                      con= cnx,parse_dates=['date'])
```

I'm not sure whether `mysql.connector` is supported in pandas `read_sql()`. You can give a try and let us know :)

Comment: Hi WoodChopper, thanks very much for your reply! I tried both, the first replied an AttributeError: 'MySQLCursor' object has no attribute 'keys'. The second doesnt work either. I also installed MySQLdb, how can I group data under MySQLdb please? Thanks

Comment: I'm sure mysqldb cursor will have keys.

Comment: Hi use `columns=[i[0] for i in cursor.description]` in mysqldb

Comment: Thanks, Thanks, I changed the code with importing MySQLdb. Columns is ok now, but parse_dates has prob, : (... I have updated the post, you can see my code and error above.

Comment: Hi remove that `parse_dates=['date']` it will infer that as date column

Comment: hi, it shows: 
    "raise PandasError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!"